# How do you add tags to AWS security groups through Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to manage AWS security groups through Ansible and want to add tags to them.
Can someone give me an example on how to do this?

For example I have a security group 'test_security_group' and I want to add a tag 'foo' to that security group.

According to Ansible documentation the [ec2_tag](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_tag_module.html) module will work but I have not been successful in using it with security groups so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
- name: Create security group for app instances
  local_action:
    module: ec2_group
    name: "http-everywhere"
    description: "My Security Group"
    vpc_id: "vpc=abcd1234"
    region: "us-east-1"
    rules: 
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 80
        to_port: 80
        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
  register: aws_sg

- name: Tag the security group with a name
  local_action:
    module: ec2_tag
    resource: "{{aws_sg.group_id}}"
    region: "us-east-1"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "My Security Group Name"
      env: "production"
      service: "web"
```

Comment: i'm always getting that the group does not exist, even though it does (logs state so and aws console), any ideas why or how to retry until success?

Answer (score 3):

As of ansible 2.4 you can specify tags directly

```
- name: Create ec2 security group
  ec2_group:
    name: SSH
    description: SSH
    vpc_id: "{{ default_vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    tags:
      Name: SSH
      Tag1: Value1
      Tag2: Value2
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        ports:
          - 22
        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```